# Getting java.sql.SQLException: No more data to read from socket

Tags: java, oracle, sockets, jdbc

I am trying to connect to oracle 11g through eclipse 3.4 jdk 1.5 tomcat 6

I am getting this error when I am trying to create a database connection with below code

> java.sql.Connection con
>   =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost::","username","password");

The stacktrace is as below:

**java.sql.SQLException: No more data to read from socket**

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1157)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIpro.receive(T4C8TTIpro.java:129)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1162)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.Display.doGet(Display.java:39)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at 
         org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have already replaced my ojdbc5.jar to work with `jre 1.5` thinking that there might be an issue with the jar file.

I have checked my `v$session` table for the number of  active connections with the below query

```
select server,machine,status from v$session;
```

32 entries were returned with 27 entries having status ACTIVE. Further the server is dedicated.

I have read somewhere that most of the connections in the pool remain in inactive state but in my case most of the connections are active. I am not sure why it is so or the problem is because of this.

I have also set the oracle parameter as `“_optim_peek_user_binds”=false` as suggested in one of the existing posts

but nothing has helped so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: please post the code/service method where exactly issue is happening

Comment: The issue is in the doGet method of a servlet. Project is simple Dynamic web project.

Comment: Exception is raised when executing this statement java.sql.Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost::","username","password");

Comment: request you to please post the code for loading drivers etc..

Comment: @sneha Is `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` invoked before calling getConnection method?

Comment: Have you tried to change localhost:: to localhost:SID or localhost/serviName?

Comment: localhost:SID was not working I changed to localhost:portnumber:servicename and it was working now.Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

localhost:SID was not working I changed to localhost:portnumber:servicename and it was working now.Thanks a lot :-) – sneha